# python print 3 strings of a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, arraylist

I'm trying get the first 3 elements of a list.

```
  1 a = "101.10.10.10"
  2 
  3 b = "102.12.12.12"
  4 
  5 
  6 asplit = a.split(".")
  7 print("a - ")
  8 print(asplit)
  9 
 10 bsplit = b.split(".")
 11 print("b - ")
 12 print(bsplit)
 13 
 14 print()
 15 print()
 16 
 17 print("---")
 18 print (a[0], a[3])
```

when i'm using this code it returns
**1** and **.**

i want to print
101 10 10

or
102 12 12

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using .split() and .join() in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43700288/using-split-and-join-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can combine list comprehension, `split()` function, `join()` function and slicing to do that. At first, we split the string from dots. Then we create a list comprehension which will eliminate empty string. Then we join it, as a final step we use the `[0:3]` slice.

```
b = "102.12.12.12"
print(' '.join([x for x in b.split('.') if x != ''][0:3]))
```

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what i needed :)

Comment: @PhilipScot I am glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: a = "101.10.10.10"

In [2]: " ".join(a.split(".")[:3])
Out[2]: '101 10 10'

In [3]: b = "102.12.12.12"

In [4]: " ".join(b.split(".")[:3])
Out[4]: '102 12 12'
```